# Best practice for reconfiguring and redeploying on AWS autoscalegroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, redeploy

I am new to AWS (Amazon Web Services) as well as our own custom boto based python deployment scripts, but wanted to ask for advice or best practices for a simple configuration management task.  We have a simple web application with configuration data for several different backend environments controlled by a command line -D defined java environment variable.  Sometimes, the requirement comes up that we need to switch from one backend environment to another due to maintenance or deployment schedules of our backend services.

The current procedure requires python scripts to completely destroy and rebuild all the virtual infrastructure (load balancers, auto scale groups, etc.) to redeploy the application with a change to the command line parameter.  On a traditional server infrastructure, we would log in to the management console of the container, change the variable, bounce the container, and we're done.

Is there a best practice for this operation on AWS environments, or is the complete destruction and rebuilding of all the pieces the only way to accomplish this task in an AWS environment?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what resources you have to change. AWS is evolving everyday in a fast paced manner. I would suggest you to take a look at the AWS API for the resources you need to deal with and check if you can change a resource without destroying it.

Ex: today you cannot change a Launch Group once it is created. you must delete it and create it again with the new configurations. but if you have one auto scaling group attached to that launch group you will have to delete the auto scaling group and so on.

IMHO a see no problems with your approach, but as I believe that there is always room for improvement,  I think  you can refactor it with the help of AWS API documentation.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to my own question.  I know the interface to AWS is constantly changing, and I don't think this functionality is available yet in the Python boto library, but the ability I was looking for is best described as "Modifying Attributes of a Stopped Instance" with --user-data as being the attribute in question.  Documentation for performing this action using HTTP requests and the command line interface to AWS can be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_ChangingAttributesWhileInstanceStopped.html